# Saddle point approximation for multiple contour integrals

Tags: co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, integration

**General Question:** Is there a reference where the saddle point approximation is applied to multiple contour integrals?

In particular, say we have the integral
$$ I_N = \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^N} \oint \left[\prod_{\ell=1}^N \frac{dq_{\ell}}{q_{\ell}^2}\right] \left(\sum_{j=1}^{N} q_{j}\right)^{N},$$
where we are applying $N$ contour integrations in sequence on curves that circle the origin in the complex plane. Using the multinomial theorem one can show that $I_N = N!$.

Using elementary symmetric polynomials, one can also show that $I_N$ can be written as

\begin{equation}
I_N = \frac{1}{(2\pi i)^{2N}} \oint \left[\prod_{\ell=1}^N\frac{dz_{\ell}}{z_{\ell}^2} \right] \left[\prod_{m=1}^N\frac{dq_{m}}{q_{m}^2} \right] \prod_{i, j=1}^N\Big(1 + z_i q_j\Big),
\label{eq:INcont}
\end{equation}

where we are now applying $2N$ contour integrations.

**Specific Question:** Is it possible to apply a multi-dimensional saddle point approximation to either form of $I_N$ to derive some form of Stirling's approximation (i.e., $N!\simeq \sqrt{2\pi N} (N/e)^N$)?

(Reposted from [stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3877175/saddle-point-approximation-for-multiple-contour-integrals) due to no answers.)